# faster way to call an Http POST Url / Service

Tags: c#, web-services, http

I call my web service by this code and it worked well. However, it's slow.
Any idea or the other way to call web service faster?

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("myurl");
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.Proxy = null;
string data = string.Format("fromidLinhVuc={0}", 0);
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
var dataStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
dataStream.Write(data);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
return response;
```

Comment: By slow, do you mean the response from the web service does not arrive quickly?

Comment: yes, it take me about 2 or 3 seconds to get response from the web service. If I use references, somehow it works fast. But I have some reason to not add reference

Comment: Do you have any solution to call web service? @KeithPayne

Comment: What do you mean, "references"?

Comment: add web reference @JohnSaunders. hope you understand it.
but dont mind it at all, I just want to know there a a way to call web service that faster than this way.

Comment: "Add Web Reference" can only be used with a SOAP web service. It doesn't look like the service you're calling is a SOAP service. Also, FYI, "Add Web Reference" is a command for the legacy ASMX technology. Even if you were trying to access a SOAP web service, you should use "Add Service Reference".

Comment: You won't be able to fix a slow web service by calling it differently. You could call it asynchronously and continue to perform work on the client while waiting for the response, but you must design the application for asynchronous operation to make it work that way.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be your problem, but you need a `using` block:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("myurl");
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.Proxy = null;
string data = string.Format("fromidLinhVuc={0}", 0);
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using (var dataStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    dataStream.Write(data);
}
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
return response;
```

Since this code is returning a `WebResponse`, which implements `IDisposable`, it is up to the caller to call this code in a `using` block, to make sure that `Dispose` is called.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a remote webservice faster by calling it this or that way. In any case, you'll have to wait for the response, and this is beyond your control. So no way here.

What you *can* do on your side, is calling the webservice asynchronously to be able to proceed while waiting for the service's response. Though not exactly making the webservice faster, this can be very beneficial, depending on your concrete scenario, actually giving the impression that things go faster:

```
public async GetMyResponseAsync()
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("myurl");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Timeout = 5000;
    request.Proxy = null;
    string data = string.Format("fromidLinhVuc={0}", 0);
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var dataStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    dataStream.Write(data);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

    return response;
}
```

Then in your calling code you might do sth. like this

```
...
// Do stuff
var response = GetMyResponseAsync();
// Do more stuff unrelated to 'response'
// Do stuff with 'response'
...
```

The part unrelated to `response` will execute immediately, while the other part will wait until `response` becomes available...